# Working on more than one project in VS Code simultaneously

Tags: visual-studio-code

Maybe it is a dummy question but while I am working on my second project in VS Code, "problems" from the first project keep appearing which is quite distracting. 
Is there a way I can freeze/deactivate the first project while I am on the second?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

you can press `control shift n` or `command shift n` on mac to open a separate, self-contained window with its own problems pane